# Remove the selected seats when the function is called ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have the following two functions which add the clicked seat to an array called seats. I can add the clicked seats to the array by this `this.props.onData(seats)` but the challenge is when I unselect the seat it needs to remove from the array. Below is my code. Is it possible to do such?

```
var seats = [] 


export default class SeatPlan extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: false
  }
 
 
  addSeatCallbackContinousCase = ({ row, number, id }, addCb, params, removeCb) => {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    }, async () => {
      if (removeCb) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 750))
        console.log(`Removed seat ${params.number}, row ${params.row}, id ${params.id}`)
        removeCb(params.row, params.number)
      }
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 750))
      console.log(`Added seat ${number}, row ${row}, id ${id}`)
      const newTooltip = `tooltip for id-${id} added by callback`
      addCb(row, number, id, newTooltip)
      // seats = {number}
      seats.push(number)
      this.setState({ loading: false })
      // console.log(seats)
      this.props.onData(seats)
    })
  }


 
  removeSeatCallback = ({ row, number, id }, removeCb) => {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    }, async () => {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1500))
      console.log(`Removed seat ${number}, row ${row}, id ${id}`)
      // A value of null will reset the tooltip to the original while '' will hide the tooltip
      const newTooltip = ['A', 'B', 'C'].includes(row) ? null : ''
      removeCb(row, number, newTooltip)
      this.setState({ loading: false })
      
    })
  }
```

[image: seat map]
[image: console]

Comment: So you just want to remove an element (seat) from an array?

Comment: yes can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `splice`:

```
seats.splice(seats.indexOf(number), 1);
this.props.onData(seats)
```